# Why call super twice in ruby contsructor/initialize method?

Tags: ruby, dalli

I was reading through [Dalli's](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) source code and I found this...

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Session
    class DalliStore < AbstractStore
      def initialize(app, options = {})
        # Support old :expires option
        options[:expire_after] ||= options[:expires]

        super

        @default_options = { :namespace => 'rack:session' }.merge(@default_options)

        @pool = options[:cache] || begin
          Dalli::Client.new(
              @default_options[:memcache_server], @default_options)
        end
        @namespace = @default_options[:namespace]

        @raise_errors = !!@default_options[:raise_errors]

        super
      end

      .... rest of class definition
```

What stood out to me is that super was called twice during initialize. I've never saw this sort of ruby idiom before. Why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the superclass initializer, I guess. Or it might be a bug.

Comment: Bug, or they specifically need to re-init (something) after their changes to the instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went to the repo to hunt down `AbstractStore` which is part of rails' actionpack. No initialize there so no behaviour that would warrant such a use. `AbstractStore` though also inherits from `Rack::Session::Abstract::ID`. Sure enough now we have the meat of it:

```
def initialize(app, options={})
  @app = app
  @default_options = self.class::DEFAULT_OPTIONS.merge(options)
  @key = @default_options.delete(:key)
  @cookie_only = @default_options.delete(:cookie_only)
  initialize_sid
end
```

Looks like the first init is to get those instance variables set up. Then use and add to them which is unsurprising: the last super though... I'm gonna take a wild guess and say that it won't do anything useful and is superfluous. I looked at core classes that inherit from AbstractStore and none of them uses multiple calls to `super`. Maybe a bug[1]. Open an issue on github and see where it leads.

[1] [This seems somewhat related](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3094-patch-ignorable-codescall-super-twice-in-memcachestore)

**EDIT:** I have overlooked another thing though, super is on the last line and thus is the return value. This might actually be a better explanation.